# How to change the below for loop code to a faster way,for example without a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I was using a for a loop to create from A0 to A49 and is saved to a list .Code below

```
A = []
B = []
C = []   
for i in range(50):
    a = 'A\_%d' % i  
    b = 'B\_%d'%i  
    c = 'C\_%d'%i  
    A.append(a)  
    B.append(b)  
    C.append(c)
```

How can i do this without for loop?

I want to improve the above code.

Since I am not good at programming. I want to improve my skills by looking into different approaches for the same.

Comment: You could do something like `A = [f"A_{i}" for i in range(50)]`

Comment: Or: `A, B, C = zip(*((f"A_{i}", f"B_{i}", f"C_{i}") for i in range(50)))`. `A`, `B` and `C` are tuples, if you really need lists you can transform them.

Comment: Thank you @Timus why it is not valid python?

Comment: @Timus Ok...My mistake.I forgot to add C = []

Comment: @Timus what is f in A = [f"A_{i}".... ?

Comment: It denotes a so-called f-string (no surprise there). In a f-string you can put variables/values between the curly braces and they are converted into a part of the string. A bit like the `'%d'%i` mechanic you are using. See [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) for a nice overview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you want an output like this:

```py
['A0', 'A1', 'A2', ... , 'A49', 'A50']
```

and all this without a separate `for` loop. It is fairly easy to do so with the help of List Comprehension, this is a lesser-known way for beginners but is very useful.
Say for example you want to store values in a list ranging from `0` to `9`.
You can do this in two ways:

1. First way is using a separate `for` loop.

```py
lst = list()
for i in range(10):
    lst.append(i)
```

This will add the values from `0` to `9` to the List `lst`.

2. Second way is relatively easy and less time-consuming, using List Comprehension.

```py
lst = list(i for i in range(10))
```

This will comprehend all the values over which `i` is iterating to the List `lst` saving lines of code, and this is what you asked for as well if I am not mistaken. This method declutters your code as well as improves it.

So the formatted code will look something like this (You can modify as per your needs):

```py
A = list(f"A{i}" for i in range(50))
```

Hope my answer helps. :)

You can refer to this article for more clarification if you need: [Python - List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

Edit 1: Removed the part pointing out the errors. You have already edited the error part of the question, your code is error free.

Edit 2: Removed unnecessary backslash